# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, debugging

I am not understanding where is the problem with the code and I tried to debug it give me cannot read properly 'push' of undefined also it's showing that acc is undefined and can someone please explain to me the code because it's confusing me

```js
const multiplyOddByTwo = (arr) => {
  return arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (curr % 2 == 0) {
      acc.push(curr);
    } else {
      acc.push(curr * 2)
    }
  }, [])
}

console.log(multiplyOddByTwo([1, 2, 3]));
```

Comment: "Cannot read property `push` of undefined" does not mean the `push` is undefined, it means that what you are calling `push` on is not an array or anything else. Hint: `acc` is `undefined`.

Comment: It does not say push is undefined it says, acc is undefined.

Comment: The callback in `reduce` should return `acc`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the error message does not say that `push` is undefined, but that the object on which `push` is called is undefined, i.e. `acc` is undefined. (You corrected this in an edit to your question).

The callback given to `reduce` should *return* the accumulating value, so it can be used for the *next* iteration, or for the final value (in case it was the last iteration). Your callback function does not return anything, so the default `undefined` value is returned implicitly. This becomes the value of `acc` in the next iteration, and so you get the error during the second iteration.

Corrected:

```js
const multiplyOddByTwo = (arr) => {
  return arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (curr % 2 == 0) {
      acc.push(curr);
    } else {
      acc.push(curr * 2)
    }
    return acc; // <----
  }, [])
}

console.log(multiplyOddByTwo([1, 2, 3]));
```

### Explanation of the code

The code builds a new array. It starts with `[]`, which is given as the last argument to `reduce`.

Then the `reduce` callback is called for each value in the input array:

That callback will be called with several arguments. The first two are named `acc` and `curr` here. `acc` is the array that is being populated, so it is `[]` in the first call of the callback, and `curr` is the currently iterated value from the input array.

With `curr % 2` we get the remainder when dividing by 2, so it will be 0 when `curr` is even, and 1 (or -1) when `curr` is odd. If even, we just want to copy the value into the new array:

```
acc.push(curr)
```

If it is odd, we want to double the value (this is the assigment):

```
acc.push(curr * 2)
```

Then this extended array is *returned* (this was missing), so it will get passed on in the next iteration.

So here are all the iterations for the example array [1, 2, 6]:

| acc | curr | push | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [] | 1 | 2 | [2] |
| [2] | 2 | 2 | [2, 2] |
| [2, 2] | 6 | 6 | [2, 2, 6] |

When all iterations have completed, the last value that was returned in the callback will become the return value of the `reduce` call, which is [2, 2, 6]  in this case.

Comment: Thank you for this amazing explanation @trincot

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to return `acc`

```js
const multiplyOddByTwo = (arr) => {
  return arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (curr % 2 == 0) {
      acc.push(curr);
    } else {
      acc.push(curr * 2)
    }
    return acc;
  }, [])
}

console.log(multiplyOddByTwo([1, 2, 3]));
```

See `Array.prototype.reduce()` documentation, it takes one reducer function with accumulator and and current value and you should to return the accumulator in order to reduce it.

For reference [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const multiplyOddByTwo = (arr) => {
  return arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (curr % 2 == 0) {
      acc.push(curr);
    } else {
      acc.push(curr * 2)
    }
    // the callback should return accumulator. Earlier it was returning undefined. 
    return acc;
  }, []) // [] is the initial value, after that returned value will be used
}

console.log(multiplyOddByTwo([1, 2, 3]));
```